# Migrating from RichFaces 3.3.1.GA to RichFaces 4.5.0.Final: what is the replacement for AjaxBehaviorRenderer and HeaderResourceProducer classes

Tags: jsf, richfaces

i am working on Richfaces migration from 3.3.1.GA to 4.5.0.Final on JSF 2.2 to achieve Wilfly Server Compatibility.

as part of that  i encountered 2 classes for which i could not find alternatives.

Below are the two classes requires alternative. Please help me on this.

import org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxBehaviorRenderer;
import org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.HeaderResourceProducer;